# Litlabs/react Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Fit'

Tags: reactjs, lit

I have MyButton component.

```
class MyButton extends LitElement {
   public fit: 'small' | 'medium' | 'large' = 'medium';
   public label = '';
}
```

I have a problem with assigning the `fit` prop when I make a react component using the `@lit-labs/react` package.

I make the component as follows:

```
export const MyButtonComponent = createComponent(React, 'my-button', MyButton, {});
```

and I try to use it as follows in React:

```
const [fit, setFit] = React.useState<string>('medium');
<MyButtonComponent label='test' fit={fit}></MyButtonComponent>;
```

The label works fine, but on the `fit` property typescript complains: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Fit'.`

Does somebody have an idea how to solve that? :)